# Need Help Regarding Submission of Iphone app without having an iphone but i have a ipod touch

Tags: iphone, app-store, ipod

I m very new to Iphone development and started making iPhone apps and not having an iPhone, 
so I'm considering buying an iPod touch,

now the question is : 1. Can i test my iphone apps in ipod touch and Submit to itunes store ?

2.Can i Create a Developer Account without having an iphone(with ipod)?

I have no idea how  to test the app on the device and/or get the app onto the app store. so kindle help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes you can test your app in iPod touch..but note that some features are available for only iPhone that are not available on iPod(call..etc..).so i will suggest you buy a phone rather than iPod

2)Can i Create a Developer Account without having an iphone(with iPod)? .-- Yes you can ..you won't have any issue with that

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you can use iPod touch! Unless of course you are using features that are only available on the iPhone device. In xCode just instead of the simulator select the device. You might have to open the organizer and then set the device as the development device. All this is performed with a single click of a button in xCode 4.X.